# How to create several DropHandlers in WPF using gong?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am using a [Gong Framework](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) in my project.
I've created the following DropHandler.
Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel : IDropTarget
{
    ObservableCollection<SomeType> Collection;

    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Problem.** I want to and another DropHandler for another `ListBox` in this window. But I don't know, how can I do it. How can I implement interface `IDropTarget` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement the interface "again" in the same class but you could bind the `DropHandler` property to an `IDropTarget` property of the view model:

```
dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding FirstDropTarget}"
```

You would then create a new class to handle the dropping. If you need a reference to the view model, you could inject it into the `IDropTarget` implementation, e.g.:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<SomeType> Collection;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        FirstDropTarget = new YourHandler(this);
        SecondDropTarget = new YourOtherHandler(this);
    }

    public IDropTarget FirstDropTarget { get; }
    public IDropTarget SecondDropTarget { get; }
}
```